# How to plot 3 time series graphs in Pandas with 3 values per time

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Using Numpy/Pandas/Matplotlib, I have a dataframe that has the following style of information.
The returned dataframe looks like this:
Each month will have a count for Sales, Engineering and Support.
Ideally I need to plot either a line graph (or bar) with 3 series, one line for Sales, another for Engineering and another for Support for each month.
Not sure how to go about this (although I suppose I could create dataframes for each series and then plot them on the same graph)

```
Month    Department           
2019-01  Sales            120
         Engineering      461
         Support          42
2019-02  Sales            92
         Engineering      428
         Support          53
2019-03  Sales            95
         Engineering      492
         Support          57
2019-04  Sales            121
         Engineering      498
         Support          58
2019-05  Sales            119
         Engineering      497
         Support          59
2019-06  Sales            89
         Engineering      423
         Support          40
2019-07  Sales            95
         Engineering      379
         Support          63
```

Not sure how to go about this (although I suppose I could create dataframes for each series and then plot them on the same graph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.unstack().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]